# FrameworkElement's OnRender method is called only for the first child

Tags: c#, wpf

So the problem is that I created a custom `Control` which holds 3 other controls deriving from `FrameworkElement`:

```
class TextArea : Control {
    private List<LocalViewBase> views;
    private Views.TextView.View textView;
    private Views.CaretView.View caretView;
    private Views.SelectionView.View selectionView;

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount => views.Count;

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) => views[index];

    public TextArea() {
        views = new List<LocalViewBase>();

        SetViews();
    }

    private void SetViews() {
        textView = new Views.TextView.View() { Margin = new Thickness(EditorConfiguration.GetTextAreaLeftMargin(), 0, 0, 0) };
        textInfo = new LocalTextInfo(textView);
        selectionView = new Views.SelectionView.View(textInfo) { Margin = new Thickness(EditorConfiguration.GetTextAreaLeftMargin(), 0, 0, 0) };
        caretView = new Views.CaretView.View(textInfo) { Margin = new Thickness(EditorConfiguration.GetTextAreaLeftMargin(), 0, 0, 0) };

        foreach (var view in new LocalViewBase[] { selectionView, textView, caretView }) {
            views.Add(view);

            AddVisualChild(view);
            AddLogicalChild(view);
        }
    }
}

public abstract class LocalViewBase : FrameworkElement { }
```

`LocalViewBase` is currently an empty class deriving from `FrameworkElement`.
The problem I'm dealing with right now is that only the `OnRender` of the earliest added child is being called - in this case `selectionView` - and only it is drawn with a proper margin. I tried @devhedgehog's answer from here: [WPF - Visual tree not used for drawing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001959/wpf-visual-tree-not-used-for-drawing) but it doesn't do the trick for me. Even if I extend the `Panel` class instead of `Control` and use its `Children` collection instead of calls to `AddVisualChild()` and `AddLogicalChild()`, still the views aren't draw with a proper margin. I also tried every method like `InvalidateWhatever()` but it also didn't help.

Probably the other views are not drawn with a correct margin, because all of them are stacked on top of each other and WPF "thinks" that only the `selectionView` is visible, so the actual question is - how do I convince it to think otherwise? :)

Comment: Aaaand why the -1 and close vote?

Comment: So you did try to override `VisualChildrenCount` and `GetVisualChild()`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post it in my question but yes - both are overriden. I'll edit my question.

Comment: We should take a step back and establish what you're actually trying to accomplish here. Is there something WPF's TextBox doesn't do that you want it to do? Composing controls in C# like this is nasty.

Comment: Wpf's `TextBox` is not suitable for my needs. I'm writing a custom code editor control - something like AvalonEdit. I was not happy with some lacking functionalities in it, and I thought it would be fun to create something like that myself. I was not mistaken, however this margin problem is really annoying.

Comment: I'm not sure where all the hate comes in when trying to build custom controls in WPF. Are most developers treating it as a WYSIWYG application builder? You should be able to create, and render, completely user drawn controls to be treated as a serious application framework otherwise we might as well stick with Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this problem was really simple. I had to extend `StackPanel` class and override the `ArrangeOverride` method (for each child to be put on x, y = 0, 0).

```
public abstract class StackablePanel : StackPanel {
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize) {
        foreach (var child in Children) {
            var uiElement = (UIElement)child;
            var rcChild = new Rect(0, 0, Width, Height);

            uiElement.Arrange(rcChild);
        }

        return arrangeSize;
    }
}
```

In one of my previous approaches to this problem I extended the `Panel` class, but it was not enough - the default implementation for `ArrangeOverride` doesn't put child `UIElement`'s as I would desire and it wasn't passing a correct `Size` instance to the child's `Arrange` method.

Now when my `TextArea` class extends this one, each of its child views is drawn correctly and its `OnRender` method is called.