# Programmatically Create WPF Datepicker for DataGrid (Not XAML)

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datepicker

I have a `DataGrid` and I want based of the data to determine the type of columns and create for these DataGrid.
That mean that I see that the field is a date then i want to have a date picker in the DataGrid.

```
             Case "CURDATE"
                 Dim col As New DataGrid Template Column
                 col.Header = "Yay"

                 Dim fac As New FrameworkElement Factory

                 Dim b As Binding = New Binding ("CURDATE")
                 fac.SetValue (DatePicker.SelectedDateProperty b)
                 Dim cellil As DataTemplate = New Data Template

                 cellil.VisualTree = fac

                 col.CellEditingTemplate = cellil
                 Ctr.Columns.Add (col)
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/444371/Creating-WPF-Data-Templates-in-Code-The-Right-Way

Comment: BTW, saying *"WPF"* and *"Not XAML"* is like saying *"I'm going to drive this car, but I refuse to put my hands on the steering wheel, and will also keep my eyes closed during the ride."* - you're going to have a very unpleasant surprise, sooner or later.

Comment: If you put all of the code in XAML, you will quickly see that your program will be as slow as a turtle. It will be better if you balance the code more. So that we don't have to wait for next christmas before it is ready.

Comment: `you will quickly see that your program will be as slow as a turtle` - Except if you know how to use XAML properly. I've done [all](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15469477/643085) [sorts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15821573/643085) of XAML based UIs and never ever had any performance issues. At all. I seriously doubt your code (which btw doesn't even compile) can perform any better than properly written XAML.

Comment: That you may think but I see no solution from you to put a date picker in a datagrid. And the piece of code that you see is part of a larger area, and if it would compile then I would not ask the question.

But I would like to challenge you with the problem where it all started with.

Comment: `get you a date picker in a data grid` - Simply override the CellTemplate.

Comment: <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker Margin="4" SelectedDate="{Binding Path=DATEOFBIRTH, StringFormat='dd/mmm/yyyy'}"></DatePicker>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

Comment: The question is how to do this programmatically.

Comment: why do you want to do that? you're hard coding bindings and your code executes inside a strange switch statement. How is your hard coded code any more "dynamic" than hard coded XAML. Also, create a proper ViewModel and all your problems will magically disappear.