# How to use animations to draw a straight line?

Tags: c#, animation, storyboard, line, universal

I want to draw a line in my code behind C# Universal app. I tried using the Line class and the line does show up, but I don't know how to make an animation so it looks like the line is being drawn in the screen instead of popping up, or instead of transferring it from outside of the screen to the location. I would like to see the animation drawing the line from point A to point B. Any idea how I can achieve this? Thanks!

I am very grateful if someone could provide an example of this

I have tried to follow this co unsuccessfully [How do you animate a line on a canvas in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469283/how-do-you-animate-a-line-on-a-canvas-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this like this:

Short explanation:

- There are two Points p1 and p2. You can set them wherever you like.
- The durationMS are the milliseconds the animation will take.
- The stepMS are the milliseconds how often a new line is drawn.
- The timer "tmr" does the animation work

we need to calculate the width of each step, the angle "k" of the line and its offset "d". Then we start the timer. Each "Tick" will do the same:

- increase the step counter
- calculate the new endpoint along the line
- draw the line

  In the last step the line is drawn with a differen color from p1 to p2.

This is a Form's code...

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestSO {

    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() { }

        PointF p1 = new PointF(10, 10);
        PointF p2 = new PointF(170, 30);

        float durationMS = 5000;
        float stepMS = 100;

        float stepWidthX;
        float k;
        float d;

        private Timer tmr = new Timer();

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            stepWidthX = (p2.X-p1.X)/ (durationMS / stepMS);

            k = (p2.Y - p1.Y) / (p2.X - p1.X);
            d = (p2.X * p1.Y - p1.X * p2.Y) / (p2.X - p1.X);
            
            tmr.Tick += tmr_Tick;
            tmr.Interval = (int)stepMS;
            tmr.Start();
        }

        private int stepCounter = 0;
        void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            stepCounter++;

            float x = p1.X + stepCounter * stepWidthX;
            float y = k * x + d;
            this.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(Pens.Black, p1, new PointF(x, y));


            if(stepCounter * stepMS > durationMS){
                stepCounter = 0;
                tmr.Stop();
                this.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(Pens.Red, p1, p2);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @ĐầuTo, As you are new to SO, please be aware, that the professionals giving answers here, are hungry for reputation points. It would be very kind of you to vote helpful answers up and - if an answer helped you to solve your problem - you should mark it as the accepted answer, This will show to others, that this question is solved. Thx!

Comment: oh, sorry, your help is very useful indeed. I tried to vote your answers. However, because I am under 15 reputation, my vote is not shown.

Comment: @ĐầuTo, No problem, please come back later, when you've got enough reputation points. If this answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it (the check below the vote counter). This is good for me (rep points) and good for others, as they see, that this question is solved. Thx