# Autosize Form containing TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a Windows Form with a bunch of Controls and it works just fine. All the Controls are contained within a `TableLayoutPanel` which autosizes according to the Controls base-size and the `Form` autosizes according to the panel, so I don't really have to worry about sizes in different platforms and computers since everything should resize according the the current configuration's settings.

For instance, here's a simple example of how it looks like.
The relevant code is:

```
//...code defining all the other Commands and .Add()'ing them to the Panel
form.Controls.Add(Panel);
form.AutoSize = true;
form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
form.ShowDialog();
```

[image: Example Dialog]

I now want to get this entire panel and place it within a TabControl so that it is just one tab amonst many others. I did this as follows:

```
//...code defining all the other Commands and .Add()'ing them to the Panel
TabControl tabControl = new TabControl();
tabControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
TabPage tabPage = new TabPage("C1");
tabPage.Controls.Add(Panel);
tabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
form.Controls.Add(tabControl);
form.AutoSize = true;
form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
form.ShowDialog();
```

So basically, instead of adding the `Panel` to the `Form`, I add it to the `TabPage` which is added to the `TabControl` which is added to the `Form`. However, this results in:
[image: Results]

The documentation states that the `AutoSize` property for `TabControl` and `TabPage` is mere infrastructure with no relevance. Most of the "solutions" I've found suggest using `.Dock = DockStyles.Fill`, which helped in that the `TabControl` now fills the Form as seen above instead of only occupying an even smaller part of it. The Form itself, however, remains unchanged.

I've thought of using the `Panel`'s size and making the `TabControl`'s size equal to (or a function of) it, but I've noticed that the `Size` parameter apparently only changes when the `Panel` is painted, since adding Controls doesn't change it at all, so I'd have to wait for the `Panel` to paint and then resize it, which sounds sloppy. Is there a better solution?

**UPDATE**
Using Anchoring and setting

```
Panel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;
tabControl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;
```

Simply lead to this:

http://img803.imageshack.us/img803/3453/5112013125710pm.jpg

Comment: Unrelated comment: Your GUI seems to be some kind of Plan drawing or diagram designer application. I STRONGLY suggest you use relevant current UI technologies for this and leave winforms behind. [`Here`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15821573/643085) is an example of a similar thing done in WPF + MVVM, supporting animations, mouse drag,  animations, and other very interesting visual and interactivity features.

Comment: Not to mention the problem you're having here (which is the lack of resolution independence of winforms) absolutely DOES NOT EXIST in newer technologies.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at that link and... that looks pretty cool. Thank you for making me spend the rest of the day learning WPF. Also... you're really passionate about WPF, I can tell.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of setting sizes, why not take advantage of [Anchoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx)?  If you anchor the `Panel` to `Top | Left | Right | Bottom` of the `TabPage`/`TabControl`, then the `TabControl` to the `Form` the same way it's only ever the `Form`'s size you need to worry about.  It will dictate the sizes of all the other items anchored to it.

Comment: Well, isn't the `Panel` anchored to its host object by default? The default value of `.Anchor = Top | Left` and I haven't modified that. As well, my idea was precisely the opposite, to let the contents of the Form decide their own size (via `.Autosize`) and then the `Form` autosizes to its content. I don't want to worry about the different possible sizes of fonts and therefore of the whole `Form` on different monitors or on different versions of Windows.

Comment: Everything is anchored `Top | Left` by default.  My suggestion (which I will edit the answer to articulate better) was that you anchor `Top | Left | Right | Bottom`.  Lock them all to the size of the `Form`, then only worry about setting the size of the `Form` from its contents.

Comment: Thanks, but oddly that actually made things worse. Adding:
`Panel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;`
`tabControl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;`
Just made the `TabControl` behave as if `.Dock != Fill`, and now it doesn't even fill the Form.
And its a real bummer that apparently there isn't a way to make the `TabControl` behave as nicely as a simple `Form` with a `Panel`, where I didn`t have to worry about the size of anything.

Answer (score -1):

use `.AutoScaleMode = None` in designer for your panel as usercontrol.
In my case TabControl-TabPage-myPage it works.