# WinForms - TabControl AutoSize not working?

Tags: c#, powershell, winforms

I have a simple Windows Form with a `TabControl`, but the `AutoSize` property doesn't seem to do anything. Here's what it looks like:

[image: form]

Here's my code:

```
$tabPage = [System.Windows.Forms.TabPage] @{
    AutoSize = $true
}
$tabControl = [System.Windows.Forms.TabControl] @{
    AutoSize = $true
}
$tabControl.Controls.Add($tabPage)
$form = [System.Windows.Forms.Form] @{
    AutoSize = $autoSize
    ClientSize = [System.Drawing.Size]::new(300, 300)
}
$form.Controls.Add($tabControl)
```

I would think the `TabControl` should fill the size of the form? I can of course set the `Size` or `ClientSize` properties, which works fine but I want it to be sized automatically vice setting a static size.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498366/autosize-form-containing-tabcontrol) asking something very similar and the solution provided was to set the `Anchor` property, but I tried that and it didn't change anything:

```
$tabControl.Anchor = @([System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Top, [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Left)
```

So what's the best way to accomplish this without setting a static size?

Comment: The documentation for TabControl says “This property is not relevant for this class.” which is probably why it doesn’t do anything - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#properties. You probably want ```Dock = “Fill”``` instead - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dockstyle?view=windowsdesktop-7.0