# Drawing an Interactive User Interface in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, drawable

Is there any way to make a user interface in WPF that replicates the following diagram?

[image: Diagram]

The idea was to have a control with three possible directions. In this control users could select the direction they want to add a new point.

For saving the point informations I was planning on using a structure like this:

```
 private Node root;

    public class Node
    {
        public int Key;
        public string Value;

        public Node left, right, forward;

        //....

    }
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15821573/643085) is an example I made for a similar requirement. It's done in WPF and MVVM. You can definitely do this yourself (maybe building on my sample) and avoid having to pay U$S1000 for third party components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to make a user interface in WPF that replicates the following diagram?

Yes.  This is definitely possible in WPF.  Many third party components, such as [WPF Diagrams](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/wpfdiagrams), demonstrate that this can be done.

If you are going to implement this yourself, I'd recommend by starting with [Shapes and Basic Drawing in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx).  This tutorial walks through the basics of drawing on a WPF `Canvas`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the series tutorial how to make a WPF diagram designer step by step.

- [Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1)
- [Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23265/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-2)
- [Part 3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23871/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-3)
- [Part 4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24681/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-4)

These series have used `Adorner` and `Thumb` object in WPF to build up WPF diagram designer which almost similar your figure.

Comment: Hm, upvoted and can't undo it. After reading the series, I found it's bad design, inefficient and unsupported. Promised future articles were never delivered. Need to find something else.

Comment: OK. Basically, I have built a similar tool base on idea of adorner layer and Thumb as well. It is an Document Image Viewer. Another hand, I suggest you can look around the tool WPF drawing tool like that: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22776/WPF-DrawTools