# Create an Object Editor in C# for WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, image, editor, richedit

I need to find, or create an editor that will handle text and images as objects. For instance I have a 3 line string of text, to be able to move it around and position it within a canvas, also the ability to add an image, and possibly resize it within that canvas. and take the result, and save it, whether I get the the offsets and positions manually, of each of the objects (preferable) , or get the entire canvas as an image, to be able to save and print.

Rulers would be great... Im not trying to re-create Photoshop, but the idea is similar.

I will be doing this in a C# WinForms application, it does seem however that a WPF solution might be better suited, and I think I can have a WPF control within winforms...

Any direction or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Forget winforms. It doesn't support anything. Your best bet is to do it in WPF and if you need, you can integrate it into an existing winforms application via the `ElementHost`.

Please see my similar answers/samples about this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15580293/643085

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15469477/643085

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15821573/643085

Also, see this example with support for zoom, panning and resizing functionality:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16947081/643085

They're all MVVM based and have some interesting features.

You can easily customize these samples and add ANY type of elements:

- images,
- geometries,
- usable interactive UI elements with functionality (TextBoxes, ComboBoxes, whatever),
- text,
- videos,
- FlowDocuments,
- or whatever that's visible on screen)

by adding additional data items and their corresponding `DataTemplates`.