# WPF C# Canvas Drawing Line connecting buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, button, canvas, line

i am testing out how to draw a line that connects the button to another button upon clicking the the button, i got confuse with the coordinates and the `settop` `setleft`, how do they actually work in simple terms. i know that we have to set the `X2` `Y2` ( subtract of start point with end point ) of the line, but i really confuse at what to subtract and how do i do this .

this is so far what i have tried:

```
 int k = 20;
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
 {
      Button btn = new Button();
      btn.Content = i.ToString();
      btn.Height = 20;
      btn.Width = 20;
      Canvas.SetTop(btn,k); // 20
      Canvas.SetLeft(btn, 20); // 10 
      Canvas1.Children.Add(btn);
      btn.PreviewMouseDown += (source, e) =>
      {
          // No idea how to set X2 , Y2 for the line's end point.
          Line line = new Line();
          //line.X2 = ;
          //line.Y2 = ;
          line.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
          line.StrokeThickness = 4;
          Canvas.SetLeft(line,40); // Suppose this is where the line should start 
          Canvas.SetTop(line ,40); // for button " 0 " .
          Canvas1.Children.Add(line);
      };
      k += 20;
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
 {
      Button btn2 = new Button();
      btn2.Content = i.ToString();
      btn2.Height = 20;
      btn2.Width = 20;
      Canvas.SetTop(btn2, k); // 20
      Canvas.SetRight(btn2, 20); // 10
      Canvas1.Children.Add(btn2);
      btn2.PreviewMouseDown += (source, e) =>
      {
          //Draw Line to connect here.
      };
      k += 20;
  }
```

i am trying to draw a line from btn to btn2 .

[image: Preview image]

And also , how do i adjust the buttons to be in the same level, for now the right buttons ( btn2 ) is abit lower than the left buttons ( btn) and i want to draw a line to connect the right buttons to the left buttons upon clicking button 0 , so 0 will draw a line to 0 .

Comment: Do not create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. the horrible winforms code behind type of stuff is not needed nor desired in WPF. Please see my examples [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15580293/643085) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15469477/643085) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15821573/643085) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16947081/643085) for the right way to do this in WPF.

Comment: +1 Those examples demonstrate a much cleaner/more correct way of doing this in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you can do it by moving the `Canvas` around, you might be better off using the positions of the `Buttons` themselves on the `Canvas`.

Essentially, you need to have two sets of coordinates, your `LineStart` and `LineEnd`, which in this case will be obtained from the two different `Buttons` you're clicking.

You could use `Point location = ((Button)source).TransformToAncestor(Canvas1).Transform(new Point(0, 0))` to obtain the location of the button being clicked, relative to the parent `Canvas`.

You would then need to do a similar thing to find the location of the original object that you had clicked (which you don't seem to be storing). You could then simply draw a line between the two calculated `Points` by setting the `X1, X2, Y1, Y2` values.

Adapting your example, you could do something like this (just to demonstrate):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Button LastClicked { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InitButtons();
    }


    public void InitButtons()
    {
        int k = 20;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Content = i.ToString();
            btn.Height = 20;
            btn.Width = 20;
            Canvas.SetTop(btn, k); // 20
            Canvas.SetLeft(btn, 20); // 10 
            Canvas1.Children.Add(btn);
            btn.PreviewMouseDown += (source, e) =>
            {
                if (LastClicked != null)
                {
                    // Get button locations.
                    Point LastClickedLocation = LastClicked.TransformToAncestor(Canvas1).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
                    Point ThisClickedLocation = ((Button)source).TransformToAncestor(Canvas1).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

                    // Stop same side lines.
                    if (LastClickedLocation.X != ThisClickedLocation.X)
                    {
                        Line line = new Line();

                        line.X1 = LastClickedLocation.X;
                        line.Y1 = LastClickedLocation.Y + btn.Height / 2; // Button Middle.
                        line.X2 = ThisClickedLocation.X + btn.Width; // Adjust Left side.
                        line.Y2 = ThisClickedLocation.Y + btn.Height / 2; // Button Middle.

                        line.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
                        line.StrokeThickness = 4;

                        Canvas1.Children.Add(line);
                    }
                }

                LastClicked = (Button)source;
            };
            k += 20;
        }

        k = 20; // Reset k, this is why your buttons weren't aligned.

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Button btn2 = new Button();
            btn2.Content = i.ToString();
            btn2.Height = 20;
            btn2.Width = 20;
            Canvas.SetTop(btn2, k); // 20
            Canvas.SetRight(btn2, 20); // 10
            Canvas1.Children.Add(btn2);

            btn2.PreviewMouseDown += (source, e) =>
            {
                if (LastClicked != null)
                {
                    // Get button locations.
                    Point LastClickedLocation = LastClicked.TransformToAncestor(Canvas1).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
                    Point ThisClickedLocation = ((Button)source).TransformToAncestor(Canvas1).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

                    // Stop same side lines.
                    if (LastClickedLocation.X != ThisClickedLocation.X)
                    {
                        Line line = new Line();

                        line.X1 = LastClickedLocation.X + btn2.Width; // Adjust Left side.
                        line.Y1 = LastClickedLocation.Y + btn2.Height / 2; // Button Middle.
                        line.X2 = ThisClickedLocation.X;
                        line.Y2 = ThisClickedLocation.Y + btn2.Height / 2; // Button Middle.

                        line.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
                        line.StrokeThickness = 4;

                        Canvas1.Children.Add(line);
                    }
                }

                LastClicked = (Button)source;
            };
            k += 20;
        }
    }
}
```

I wouldn't recommend using this exact code, as it's not particularly bright about handling `Button` clicks and deciding when to draw lines, but it should demonstrate the drawing and obtaining coordinates that you're after.

Comment: thanks for the effort , but what is lastclicked? the coordinates of the button which is last click?

Comment: I'd missed that out from the sample, it was just a class level Button property to hold the last thing you'd clicked on (I've amended the example).

Comment: hi thanks for the effort and time . it works good but i am looking for is like 0 connect to 0 , 1 connect to 1 .. so right now if i click 0 to 0 and then 1 , it connects the 0 to the 1 forming a Z line . And if i were to add a margin in the buttons , i have to take into account the margins too?

Comment: You could try comparing the Button.Content property to check for the same content. I believe you would have to take the margins into account.