# WPF keeping track of an elements position

Tags: wpf, transformation

Im creating a node based editor, where nodes are stored in a canvas, and each node has multiple ellipse elements representing input/outputs.

I'm having trouble figuring out where to draw the start points and end points of each line though. Currently, I get the nodes view(by using the ItemGenerator.GetContainerFromItem), then find the ellipse controls by walking the visual tree, and transforming the point [0,0] from ellipse local space to canvas local space, and draw the line in canvas space. I then refresh whenever the nodes position changes.

This works to some extent but not in the following situations

1) the layout of the node changes, for example when the node is resized or one of its panels is updated, causing ellipses to be shifted/positioned differently relative to the node itself.

2) sometimes when Im adding lots of nodes, the nodes view isn't loaded for whatever reason and so walking the visual tree fails to find the ellipses.

Things Ive tried

-solving issue 1 with layoutupdate events, but these events are raised for every control, and so is horribly slow. I only want to update when I need to, not when some unrelated control is updated.

-solving issue 2 by dispatching updates with background priority in the hope the control is loaded. this helps, but can still fail every now and then

I want to say something like

Bind Line P1 to [Ellipse Position transformed to canvas space]

any ideas?

Comment: Are you writing the lines inside OnRender method? Are you using virtualization and therefore you sometimes cant find a node since it might not be realized yet? Post us code where you decide to draw the lines or upload the project somewhere online so we can run it. My suggestions would be to fire an event once you realized that the positions of your nodes or size of your nodes have changes which shall happen inside the MeasureOverride method since you need to measure elements anyways. When event fired try to update the drawing of your lines. Its just an suggestion. I need more code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you don't need any of the things you're doing.

See my examples for the right way to do this in WPF (MVVM)

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15580293/643085) /
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15469477/643085) /
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15821573/643085) /
[4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16947081/643085)

Comment: From example 3(which looks most like what I want) you are manually specifying the snap point positions in code as an offset from the node position. I dont want to specify the snappoints position manually, I want to declare the layout for the snappoint views, say in a grid or something, and have the positions based off that

Comment: @Pastillman the ViewModel-First approach is most easy for these kind of things. If you create the UI elements in the `DataTemplate` (not based on actual data) You will have a hard time figuring out what the actual `X,Y` values are for those elements.