# Databinding explanation

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

i tried out the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16947081/2111258

I have gotten the code to work, but I dont understand how the slider in the dockpanel has the ScaleFactor property bound. Using breakpoints i found out that its bound to the MainWindow's ViewModel object.

How does the bind definition "{Binding ScaleFactor}" bind it to the property of a completely different object belonging to the MainWindow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something but I don't see anything unusual there.

Object the view is bound to is specified in `DataContext` property:

```
DataContext = ViewModel = new PanZoomViewModel();
```

`PanZoomViewModel` contains `ScaleFactor` property which value is read and updated by view when changed in UI. And when it is changed in code its setter fires `OnPropertyChanged` event, so view knows it should update corresponding UI element.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to WPF so I don't know how databinding works yet, based on the term DataContext i found http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321899/DataContext-in-WPF which explained more in detail, thanks again