# Drawing shapes in C# using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to draw a series of squares in C#. This is my first foray into WPF. My `SpaceProbeView` class has a `SetModel` function that allows the user to pass the data on the squares that will be rendered.

Once the `model` has been set, `SpaceProbeView` iterates through the 2D array that is the model. Each cell has data on what type of space it is, and the `SpaceProbeView` sets the color of the square to draw based on the space type.

With the code I have right now it just keeps drawing the squares at the same position, and I've been looking through documentation and can't figure out how to adjust the position of each `Rectangle`.

Here is my `SpaceProbeView`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SpaceProbe
{
    public class SpaceProbeView
    {
        Window window = new Window();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        private int cellSize = 25;
        SpaceProbeModel model;
        int rowAndColumnSize;
        SolidColorBrush emptySpaceBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        SolidColorBrush asteroidBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        SolidColorBrush gravityWellBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        SolidColorBrush gravityInfluencedBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        Brush outlineBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;

        public SpaceProbeView(int size)
        {
            emptySpaceBrush.Color = Colors.Blue;
            asteroidBrush.Color = Colors.Brown;
            gravityWellBrush.Color = Colors.LightGray;
            gravityInfluencedBrush.Color = Colors.Gray;

            rowAndColumnSize = size;
            window.Title = "Space Probe";
            canvas.Width = rowAndColumnSize * cellSize;
            canvas.Height = rowAndColumnSize * cellSize;
            window.Width = rowAndColumnSize * cellSize;
            window.Height = rowAndColumnSize * cellSize;
            window.Content = canvas;

            window.Show();
        }

        public void SetModel(SpaceProbeModel aModel)
        {
            model = aModel;
            for (int row = 0; row < rowAndColumnSize; row++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < rowAndColumnSize; column++)
                {
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
                    rect.Width = cellSize;
                    rect.Height = cellSize;
                    rect.Stroke = outlineBrush;
                    rect.RenderTransform = new Point(row * cellSize, column * cellSize);

                    switch (model.cellType[row, column])
                    {
                        case SpaceProbeModel.type.asteroid:
                            rect.Fill = asteroidBrush;
                            break;
                        case SpaceProbeModel.type.gravityInfluenced:
                            rect.Fill = gravityInfluencedBrush;
                            break;
                        case SpaceProbeModel.type.gravityWell:
                            rect.Fill = gravityWellBrush;
                            break;
                        case SpaceProbeModel.type.empty:
                            rect.Fill = emptySpaceBrush;
                            break;
                    }
                    canvas.Children.Add(rect);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Delete all that and use proper XAML.

Comment: @HighCore Seriously? Is that how it's done? I know nothing about WPF.

Comment: Yep. Seriously. Start reading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/) and see my examples [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15580293/643085) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15469477/643085) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15821573/643085) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16947081/643085) about how to create diagrams / shapes items-based UIs using WPF best practices such as DataBinding, ItemsControls and DataTemplates.

Comment: @HighCore Okay cool.