# C# - how to anchor to shapes with a line between them

Tags: c#, graphics, graphical-interaction

I've been searching all day for many different graphics tuts but there's still a couple off examples that I can't find. I'm trying to create a graphical editor and one of the required functions I need is for the editor to be able to take a rectangle and a circle and connect them or anchor them together with a line or arrow (like a Petri Net editor). If there's nothing for the line to connect to the arrow should disappear (so they need to recognize they're connected).

Where can I find like a massive tutorial (and even source code samples) that has nothing but examples demonstrating Graphics and interaction skills like this(whether written or video tut)?

I'd really appreciate your help
Thanks!!!

Comment: GDI or WPF? still to decide?

Comment: Please see [my example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15821573/643085)  and [my previous example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15580293/643085) about this.

Comment: Thanks fellas, I saw a video tut on on GDI+ but I couldn't get it to work in my app (or at least I think it wouldn't work) because it was an old version of GDI. I'll try both suggestions --FelicePollano--, and @HighCore I'm checking your example now. Thank you Very Much!!!

Comment: @HighCore Dude I totally see what your talking about and I'm pissed cause I started building this project already and I don't have much time left, plus I don't know WPF as well as I know WINFORMS. But it seems like from what your saying is that I'm not gonna get that great of performance with WINFORMS. If you don't mind please let me know how get in contact with you just to ask a few questions. PLEASE!! picodegallo@zoho.com  Please drop me a line if you can Bruh!!! (I aint scared to donate either)

Comment: @PicoDeGallo Check your inbox :)