# Line between 2 controls doesn't redraw

Tags: c#, wpf, button, line

I have b `Buttons` created dynamically by code and I want to draw a `Line` between the first node and the last in the same `StackPanel`. The problem is that whenever I call this function it doesn't make the line from the first to the b `Button` but instead it move the line to the right.

My code for the `Line` draw function:

```
public void CreateALine()
{
    redLine = new Line();

    redLine.X1 = nodul_nou[0].Margin.Left ;
    redLine.Y1 = nodul_nou[b].Margin.Top - 40;

    redLine.X2 = nodul_nou[b].Margin.Left ;
    redLine.Y2 = nodul_nou[b].Margin.Top - 40;

    SolidColorBrush redBrush = new SolidColorBrush();

    redBrush.Color = Colors.Black;
    redLine.StrokeThickness = 4;
    redLine.Stroke = redBrush;

    workplace.Children.Add(redLine);
}
```

`Note:` `nodul_nou[b]` is the `Button` I am speak about, It does not draw a line between the first `Button`, `nodul_nou[0]`, and the b `Button`, `nodul_nou[b]`.

Comment: I think there is a typo: `redLine.Y1 = nodul_nou[b]` should be `redLine.Y1 = nodul_nou[0]`.

Comment: 1 - a `StackPanel` is not an adequate container for this. You need a `Canvas` or something. 2 - You don't "draw" stuff in WPF by using procedural code like this, you create the proper data and let the UI yourself. 3 - Don't create or manipulate UI elements in code in WPF, the winforms approach is not needed nor desired in WPF. Post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore So I should make the line in xaml and then modify it from code ?

Comment: @LPL Both the buttons are on the same point on Y axis, only the X component is different

Comment: @VladVlad no. You should create a proper ViewModel and have the UI databound to that ViewModel, and probably use an `ItemsControl` to dynamically generate UI elements from the Collections in the ViewModel. Again, post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the right way to do it in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore www.imgur.com/VOnKojL As you can see in this picture I the image the rectangles are the buttons also you can consider the lines as button too and I want to draw the red line, but the user can always add new rectangles and lines ( both of them buttons ) and both of them are part of the array nodul_nou[], if the user adds a new button I want to make that line from the first to the new button(the new button will follow the same order). My problem is that when I use the code from my post it does not draw the line to the last button but it just move it to the right.

Comment: @VladVlad that really looks similar to [my sample](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15821573/643085) of some kind of diagram designer, you don't need any code to do that, you need an `ItemsControl` and a couple of `DataTemplates`. WPF is very different from other frameworks. You can download my sample code and see how it works, so you can understand how this is done in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore Thanks, I'll take a look over your sample.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33873/discussion-between-vlad-vlad-and-highcore)