# Remove Points without clearing the screen

Tags: c#, graphics, system.drawing

I am using the `CreateGraphics().DrawLine` functions to draw graphs in my program, and want to continuously update these points.

The only way I found to remove lines from the screen was to `Refresh()` it. The thing is, this removes all of the lines (or segments of the line).

What I want to do is to clear one part (or segment) of a line, and replace it with another, without having to draw all of the other points again as well.

Example: Initial line is : (x and y coordinates)

> 1,1->2,2; 2,2->3,3; 3,3->4,4...

Now I just want to make the first part: `4,4->2,2;` and leave the rest.

Additional info: 
I am using windows forms, not WPF

Comment: Are you using WPF or WinForms?

Comment: Just don't use CreateGraphics.  Minimize your window and restore it to see how it that's just not the right method to use.

Comment: What would you suggest using? :)

Comment: @user2755408 Paint everything in a `Paint` event handler or `OnPaint` overridden method.

Comment: `to draw graphs in my program` - You might want to check [My Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15821573/643085) on that using relevant technologies.