# What is the best approach for dynamic drawing in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, drawing

Based on some available data in the database I would like to create an application which will show a graphical representation of that data. I have decided to choose WPF technology.

This is an example diagram I would like to draw when a user request it:

[Node 1] (rectangle)----->[Node 2] (circle) -------> [Node 3] (rectangle) -----> [Node 4] (circle)

My question is - what is the best approach to draw items like that on the form? Should I use dynamic drawing techniques or something else?

I am new to WPF technology as I am .NET windows form software developer.

Comment: Not enough info. Will the user be able to interact with the nodes? How many nodes will there typically be?

Comment: Yes, the user should be able to interact with the nodes by selecting them and i.e. seeing properties of the node. I expect maximum of 50 nodes per one query.

Comment: Please see my examples [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15580293/643085) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15821573/643085) about this. Full source code included.

Comment: Where can I find them?