# Visualising an ERD with WPF

Tags: wpf, web, visualization, entity-relationship, diagram

Does anyone know of a Web or WPF control for visualising a (kind of) Entity Relationship Diagram.

I have a number of objects of different types and I need to provide an interactive environment for navigating around the objects using the relationships between them.

Has anyone done anything similar?

EDIT: I should have explained that I'd like the control to auto-populate (or have programmatic control over its population) given a relational dataset and ideally for the diagram to readjust when one or another object is selected.

Perhaps something a bit like [this example](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/radial.html) but more star shaped and free or at least cheaper!

Comment: You may want to have a look at [my example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819318/how-to-create-and-connect-custom-user-buttons-controls-with-lines-using-windows/15821573#15821573) of a similar thing.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not after a design interface - I'm after a read-only interactive viewer.

Comment: then remove the edit capabilities from my example and that would be enough. What specific features are you looking for? BTW asking for recommendations on tools or libraries is off-topic in StackOverflow.

Comment: OK, thanks, is there a sibling site for asking such questions?

Comment: @try programmers.stackexchange.com, BTW that javascript stuff doesn't look like a big deal, you should be able to do that in WPF with a couple lines of XAML and some ViewModels.

Comment: take a look at [my other example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579069/graph-nodes-coordinates-evaluation/15580293#15580293)

Comment: Thanks, will do - yeah I've seen what I'm after already a couple of years ago.  Just didn't bookmark it and can't find it now... :-(

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to go from the http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24681/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-4

It was created in 2008 but still rocks. It has the [connector routing](http://ww2.cs.mu.oz.au/~pjs/papers/gd09.pdf) and the ability to add / remove shapes. You probably only need a subset of the functionality.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not after a design interface - I'm after a read-only interactive viewer.

Comment: Yes, if you remove the design elements. The hardest part is the layout of elements and the orthagonal routing.