# DrawingImage event handlers in WPF

Tags: wpf, events, graph, drawing, handlers

Is it possible to set up event handlers on the parts of the drawing, which is obtained with DrawingImage?
For example, I make the graph drawing (mathematical graph with vertices and edges), graph is loaded from txt file, and I want to make vertices movable (with incident edges) but I don't know how to do that, since I've made a drawing with DrawingImage.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't "draw" stuff in WPF. You create the proper data and let the UI "draw" itself. Post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Comment: Start reading [WPF Graphics Rendering Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373.aspx) and [Drawing Objects Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751619.aspx) and [Shapes and Basic Drawing in WPF Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx).

Comment: This is a screenshot of graph with 40 nodes. You can see there are some crossing edges, which doesn't look nice. I want to make nodes moveable, so user can make a better picture for himself, because the real program will have much more nodes then this graph and more crossing edges.

http://tinypic.com/r/2dl9mhw/5

@HighCore

Answer (score 0):

That really looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15580293/643085), except I took a completely different approach to it.

The default approach to WPF is something called [MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381402/wpf-programming-methodology/14382137#14382137), where, as I mentioned, you don't "tell the UI to do things", but instead you define the proper data, and use [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx) to let the UI "draw itself".

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I've been doing some research about MVVM pattern. Unfortunately I can't run your example to see how it works.. I have this exception: Service provider is missing the INameResolver service. Can you tell me how to solve this, please?

Comment: @Daisy I never ever saw that before. Can you show me the full exception with the stack trace etc?

Comment: WOW! I just started your project somehow and it's great, it may help me a lot! But, when I open the MainWindow.xaml I still have the two errors which are the same. Except the above description of exception, there are no further information. It happens at line 32, 33 on the {x:Reference view spot ( <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding DataContext.Connectors,Source={x:Reference view}}"/>
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding DataContext.Nodes,Source={x:Reference view}}"/>  ).

Comment: Also, when I try to open your project, first, I have this:The associated source control plug-in is not installed or could not be initialized. Common causes for this error include server unavailability and/or incorrect workspace mappings.

Comment: @Daisy the source control thing is normal, the other one I don't know.

Comment: I found full exception with the stack trace, I would divide it into two comments because it's too long:
   at System.Windows.Markup.Reference.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.Core.InstanceBuilderOperations.SetValue(Object target, IProperty propertyKey, Object value)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.ModifyValue(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode target, IProperty propertyKey, Object value, PropertyModification modification)
   at

Comment: Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.UpdateProperty(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode, IProperty propertyKey, DocumentNode valueNode)

Comment: I have one more question about your project. Is it necessarily to use ObservableCollection (I know that is because of MVVM pattern)? In my project, data is represented with Dictionary, so I don't know how to adjust it...do I have to change the whole concept of data representation?
- And, how did you make a background table with squares where nodes getting moved, and implemented the "moving" part? Can it be invisible for user?

Comment: @Daisy What do you use dictionaries for? put relevant data in the `Node` class instead, and use `ObservableCollection`s. I don't like dictionaries.

Comment: The electrical elements (nodes and edges in graph) are represented with dictionaries because they all have ID as a key.

Comment: I still don't know how to solve that error.
Can this be coded differently?
<CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding DataContext.Connectors,Source={x:Reference view}}"/>
<CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding DataContext.Nodes,Source={x:Reference view}}"/> 

Something's wrong with Source={x:Reference view} part.

Comment: @Daisy are you compiling against full .Net Framework 4.0? That should not be a problem. I have the project running here. Are you using Visual Studio 2010 or 2012? My environment is Visual Studio 2010 SP1 on Windows 7. I don't know if that could cause a problem?

Comment: @Daisy the background is just a `VisualBrush`, if you don't want it, just remove it from the XAML. The movement is performed by the `Thumbs` and the "grid snapping" occurs in the Model (the `Node` Class) where the `X` and `Y` values are always forced to multiples of 50. So if you `Node.X = 35;` then the value will be forced to `Node.X == 50`;

Comment: @Daisy With regards to dictionaries and stuff. Your entity Model should be self-sufficient in the sense that a single class should contain all the relevant information to be able to be saved into a database (without depending on dictionaries of any sort). So if you need the `Nodes` to have and Id, then put a `public int Id {get;set;}` in the `Node` class instead. Don't use dictionaries for data representation.

Comment: My version is 4.0.30319 RTMRel, 2010, and I found out the problem is with VS - http://xstatic2.wordpress.com/2011/10/06/xreference/#comment-15 .
Is there any other way to concatenate the Nodes and Connectors in a single one?

Comment: @Daisy I guess you can do it at the ViewModel level, by creating an `ObservableCollection<DiagramObject>` which is the base class of Nodes and Connectors, but you will have to listen to `CollectionChanged` events in the Nodes and Connectors Collection and add these to the "Merged" collection as well.