# Drawing a binary tree in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, treeview, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

Basically, I want to display a binary tree in WinRT. I have an `ObservableCollection` which contains the values of the nodes.

What do you think is the best way to start trying with?

Comment: You should be able to reuse most of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579069/graph-nodes-coordinates-evaluation/15580293#15580293) in WinRT, though you'll probably need to change some XAML because there are several XAML features which are absent in WinRT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a "standard" `TreeView` control doesn't satisfy your aesthetic needs - you could either try to build a tree out of some `Shape` elements, possibly connected and most likely laid out on a `Canvas` or alternatively to support huge trees - use DirectX - either with a native WinRT component or using SharpDX.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your own panel(custom), to achieve your requirement,

```
   public class MyBinaryTreePanel : Panel
    {
        public double MaxRowHeight { get; set; }
        public MyBinaryTreePanel()
        {
            MaxRowHeight = 0.0;
        }
        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {            
            double rowHeight=0;
            double columnWidth = finalSize.Width;
            int total = Children.Count;
            int temp = total;

            int count = 0;
            do
            {
                temp /= 2;
                count++;
            } while (temp != 1);
            count++;           
            int Row = count;   
            MaxRowHeight = finalSize.Height / total;

            double temrow = 0;
            int i = 0;
            for (int a = 0; a < Row; a++)
            {
                double temp34 = 0;
                double tempColumn = 0;                

                columnWidth = ((finalSize.Width) / (Math.Pow(2, a)));
                for (int b = 0; b < (Math.Pow(2, a)); b++)
                {
                    if (i < total)
                    {
                        rowHeight = Children[i].DesiredSize.Height > MaxRowHeight ? Children[i].DesiredSize.Height : MaxRowHeight;
                        Children[i].Arrange(new Rect( tempColumn,  temrow, columnWidth, rowHeight));
                        i++;
                        if (rowHeight >= temp34)
                        {
                            temp34 = rowHeight;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            rowHeight = temp34;
                        }
                        tempColumn += columnWidth;
                    }

                }
                temrow += temp34;

            }//
            return finalSize;
        }
        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
        {
            int total = Children.Count;
            int temp = total;
            int count = 0;
            do
            {
                temp /= 2;
                count++;
            } while (temp != 1);
            count++;
            int Row = count;
            MaxRowHeight = (availableSize.Height) / Row;
            Size MyDesiredSize = new Size();
            int i = 0;
            for (int a = 0; a < Row; a++)
            {
                double value2 = 0.0;
                for (int b = 0; b < (Math.Pow(2, a)); b++)
                {
                    if (i < total)
                    {
                        Children[i].Measure(availableSize);
                        double value1 = Children[i].DesiredSize.Height;

                        if (value1 >= value2)
                        {

                            MyDesiredSize.Height = value1;
                            value2 = value1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MyDesiredSize.Height = value2;

                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                MyDesiredSize.Height = MyDesiredSize.Height > MaxRowHeight ? MyDesiredSize.Height : MaxRowHeight;
            }
                           return MyDesiredSize;
        }
    }
```

I hope it will help you,

Regards,
Joy Rex

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TreeView` control from WinRT Xaml Toolkit.

Here's sample usage: https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample/Views/Controls/TreeViewTestPage.xaml

The control is ported from Silverlight Toolkit with the original as well as a touch friendlier template available. You can find [WinRTXamlToolkit on NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit).