# Line is not displayed on startup but becomes visible on resize (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, frameworkelement, drawingcontext, onrender

I have a WPF application where a line shape is only displayed when the application window is resized, as shown here:

[image]

The red line is drawn on-the-fly, it is not defined in XAML.  It displays fine.

The blue line is defined in XAML, but its dimensions are changed within the `OnRender()` call.  If its dimensions are not changed, or if only **some** of its dimensions are changed, the blue line is displayed on startup.  But when **all** the dimensions of the blue line are changed, it is **not** displayed on startup.  It is only displayed on application resize.

Here's the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="canvas_line.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:canvas_line" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="284" Width="228">
    <Canvas Name="canvas">
        <local:show_line />
        <Line Name="my_line" Stroke="Blue" 
            X1="50" Y1="40" X2="50" Y2="80" StrokeThickness="4" />
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

And the C# code-behind file:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Linq;

namespace canvas_line
{
    public partial class show_line: FrameworkElement
    {
        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
        {
            base.OnRender(dc);              // Good practice.

            // Draw a brand-new red line defined here only 
            // (not defined in XAML).

            Pen dp = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 4);
            dc.DrawLine(dp, new Point(100, 150), new Point(100, 200));

            // Now modify coordinates of the blue line defined in XAML.

            Canvas cp = (Canvas)this.Parent;
            var my_line = cp.Children.OfType<Line>().FirstOrDefault();
            my_line.X1 = 100;
            my_line.Y1 = 20;
            my_line.X2 = 100;
            my_line.Y2 = 50;

            // Problem: The blue line is not displayed unless
            // the application window is resized.
        }
    }
}
```

The zip file for the entire project is here (there is very little code in the project, I have pruned it to the absolute minimum necessary to demo the problem):

https://anonfiles.com/file/18c6edce296927b43ed0b0d595574a80

I have tried all sorts of combinations of calls to `UpdateLayout()` and `InvalidateVisual()`, to no effect.  Why is this happening, and is there a workaround?  My ultimate goal is to be able to animate the blue line so as to have it blink.

I am on Windows 7, Visual Studio 10, .NET 4.0 Client Profile.

Comment: PS: I need to have the call to `OnRender()` because, although not shown here, I have to do low-level glyph drawing.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing the location prior to the base.OnRender?

Comment: @JohnKoerner  Yes, does not work.

Comment: I suspect you are clearing the drawing context in `base.OnRender()`.  Would you be able to post that code?  Alternatively, you could check to see if removing the `base.OnRender()` brings back the blue line.

Comment: @TylerKendrick I removed `base.OnRender()`, made no difference.

Comment: My only other suggestion would be to attempt calling different `.Invalidate*()` methods on the `my_line` object.  Because you are already in OnRender, it may not be updating correctly.

Comment: @TylerKendrick I tried your suggestion and called those methods after `InitializeComponent()` but it did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you put it like this it will draw properly

```
 <Canvas Name="canvas">
    <Line Name="my_line" Stroke="Blue" X1="50" Y1="40" X2="50" Y2="80" StrokeThickness="4" />
    <local:show_line />
 </Canvas>
```

Comment: Works, thank you! Why is this?  Have you seen this behavior before, and is that how you came up w/ the fix?

Comment: @Henna Patil: +1 Good catch.