# Move two connected components in C# WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am developing a C# application and I am drawing two components programmatically. However, I would like to make them connected (using line) so that when I move one component, I can change the coordinates of another object.

For example: Suppose there are two squares on Canvas and they are connected using a line. When a move one square, I also want to change the coordinates of another square. So, another square will also seem like moving relative to first one.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out in second part. I think it can be done using dependency properties but I wasn't able to find an example.

Comment: Just attach a `MouseMove` handler to the first object and then move the second object from there... nothing to do with `DepenedencyProperty`s.

Comment: Yes that's true. But in this case, I would to manually alter the coordinates of every other component. So, I wanted to know is there any other alternative

Comment: You'd only ever need to update 2 values: `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left`.

Comment: From your terminology, it seems that you're approaching this with a winforms mentality, which is not compatible with WPF. See [My Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15580293/643085) which shows how to do this in a proper WPF way using WPF techniques.

Comment: I am still not sure. How to do that