# How to create drag and droppable points (in a grid) overlaying a bitmap?

Tags: winforms, drag-and-drop, c++-cli, grid-layout, windows

I want to design and code a simple UI, my question is how do you create a grid where the crossing lines form dots or just dots arranged in a grid overlaying an image. The dots in the grid should be 'drag and drop'-able to place them over dots in the image for calibration purposes.

The program then needs to call some C(++) functions through a DLL with the offset from the standard grid dot to the new position.
I'm currently using Windows forms with C++/CLI.

There are plenty of drag and drop tutorials, I thought of determining the position difference from the drag and the drop event and then placing the dot in the new position as the drop event is registered by the underlying `PictureBox` or some container.

But is there a dot control I can use, do I need to adapt a small button or make my own control?
And is it possible that I have lines between these dots to represent the (moved) grid? (or just draw and update lines drawn between the points manually?)

Am I approaching this the right way and / or is there another GUI framework that is more suited for this?

(I have not much experience with this and my search terms didn't bring me some useful information, any further reading is appreciated, too)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15580293/643085