# WPF control for neural net visualization

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I'm developing a Neural net, and for visualization I'm writing a UserControl in WPF.

The following code draws the neurons:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ExcelAddIn.LogView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ellipse">
        <Grid  Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Input, StringFormat=N2}" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Output, StringFormat=N2}" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,22,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="panel">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="70" Margin="100,0,0,0">
            <ItemsControl x:Name="Items" ItemsSource="{Binding Neurons}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ellipse}"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="Panel" ItemsSource="{Binding Layers}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource panel}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

[image: Drawn neurons]

I would like to draw lines between the Neurons like this:

[image: Weights]

So for each neuron in the specific layer should have a line to each neuron in the next layer (drawing all the lines would made it harder to understand, so I didn't draw all the lines on the illustration). I would like to achieve this with binding. Is it possible? (I don't care if my existing code needs to be refactored, if that solves my problem.)

Note: I have a Weight object (a line would represent this weight). One Weight object has reference to two Neurons, a double, that is the weight between them and some other properties. And the weigths can be accessed from the datacontext of the usercontrol.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [the Nodes Editor example (from the another answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15580293/490018) should help. It is necessary to create instances of appropriate `ViewModel`s (`Node` and `Connector` classes). Please note that `Node` coordinates must be filled before displaying (see the implementation of the `NodesDataSource` class).

### Additional references to articles/libraries:

1. [NetworkView: A WPF custom control for visualizing and editing networks, graphs and flow-charts](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182683/NetworkView-A-WPF-custom-control-for-visualizing-a).
2. [Graphviz4Net library](http://graphviz4net.codeplex.com/): provides WPF control that is capable of generating "nice looking" graph layouts).
3. [Graph# library](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/): a graph layout framework, it contains some layout algorithms and a GraphLayout control for WPF applications.