# Need to choose WinForms/WPF tree view control

Tags: wpf, winforms, graph, treeview

I'm looking for free/non-profit WinForms/WPF tree view control.
The tree hierarchy should look exactly like in attached image:
[image]

Comment: Looks like you really want a flow chart type control.  Most tree view controls will not display anything like this.

Comment: You can adapt [my example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15580293/643085) to support multiple shapes. Forget winforms, its completely useless.

Comment: It doesn't seem completely useless to me >;) https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Chart/?gclid=CNXGh8mz9sgCFQq3GwodRxMGew

Comment: The fact that the first example I found costs money is completely irrelevant here. Don't you feel that this religious fanaticism is ridiculous? Both WinForms and WPF are perfect for making professional products, both are legacy technologies in favor of WinRT, and both of them will be supported until Windows exists. In case of a new project, choosing WPF *could be* a reasonable choice. Otherwise, I would use the technology of the already existing project and I would not mix WPF and WinForms, because that can cause many problems.

Comment: @taffer `Both WinForms and WPF are perfect for making professional products` - well, except for the fact that winforms requires 6 or 7 steps to do a simple `<TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}"/>`... don't you think? If productivity matters, then winforms is a big no-no.